# Challenge: For Loops - Updating Array Elements

Tags: javascript, for-loop

**Goal -->** I am trying to complete a codesmith challenge: For Loops - Updating Array Elements

> Using a FOR loop, write a function addN which adds the argument n to
> each number in the array arr and returns the updated arr.

Problem --> the for loop only console logs a single value (4 and 5 for each log) and does not update each value in the array.

**My input -->** I have googled and watched youtube videos on for loops and forEach, but I am still at a wall.  I believe something is wrong in my return as it returns only a single value and not an updated array. Please can you point me in the right direction...

**my code -->**

```js
function addN(arr, n){
  // ADD CODE HERE
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
   
    return arr[i] += n;
     // return number;
  }
 
} 

// Uncomment these to check your work!
console.log(addN([1, 2, 3], 3)); // expected log [4, 5, 6]
console.log(addN([3, 4, 5], 2)); // expected log [5, 6, 7]
```

Comment: Your loop `return`s after the first iteration, you want to `return arr;` *after*  the loop is done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must return all array instead of single for loop like:

```js
function addN(arr, n){
  // ADD CODE HERE
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
     arr[i] += n;
  }
  return arr;
 
} 

// Uncomment these to check your work!
console.log(addN([1, 2, 3], 3)); // expected log [4, 5, 6]
console.log(addN([3, 4, 5], 2)); // expected log [5, 6, 7]
```

Answer (score 0):

The return must be placed after the loop:

```js
function addN(arr, n){
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    arr[i] += n;
  }
  return arr;
} 

// Uncomment these to check your work!
console.log(addN([1, 2, 3], 3)); // expected log [4, 5, 6]
console.log(addN([3, 4, 5], 2)); // expected log [5, 6, 7]
```

Also, you can check the high order function [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
function addN(arr, n){
  return arr.map(x => x + n);
} 

// Uncomment these to check your work!
console.log(addN([1, 2, 3], 3)); // expected log [4, 5, 6]
console.log(addN([3, 4, 5], 2)); // expected log [5, 6, 7]
```